# Set the OK button in an alert to run location.reload method

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

How would I call the OK button, in an alert message box button to run location.reload()? I have another button on my page that I do not want to run this function below,  what is the best way to call only the alert button to this method?

```
$('button')location.reload(true)
```

Comment: If you mean the native alert, you're out of luck, native alert always returns `undefined`.

Answer (score 0):

An effective approach to this is to perform the reload as a result of a call to `confirm()`.

```
var _confirm = confirm("confirmation message");

if (_confirm) {
window.location.reload();
}
```